# python Multiprocess with two list compare

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I have the question on `multiprocess` in `python3.5`.

If i have two list like:

```
xlist = [1,2,3]
ylist = [4,5,6]
```

and I want to do :

```
for i in xlist:
    for j in ylist:
        print (i*j)
```

the output is

```
4
5
6
8
10
12
12
15
18
```

I try to do that like this with Multiprocess:

```
import multiprocessing

global xlist
xlist = [1,2,3]
ylist = [4,5,6]

def product(ylist): 
    for x in xlist:
        for y in ylist:
            print (x,y)
    return 'OK'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    results = []
    for i in range(0, len(ylist)):
        result = pool.apply_async(job, args=(ylist,))
        results.append(result)
        # print (result.get())
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

for result in results:
    print(result.get())
```

But I can not got the output show above. My output will be

```
1 4
1 5
1 6
2 4
2 5
2 6
3 4
3 5
3 6
1 4
1 5
1 6
2 4
2 5
2 6
3 4
3 5
3 6
1 4
1 5
...
```

with the code.

Are there any ways to achieve the goal (must use multiprocess)?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I want to do deal with big data, so I have to use multiprocess to process the computation. But I have no idea how to use multiprocessing to process two list

Comment: I meant " I can not got the result i want." is a red flag in an SO question. It's too vague

Comment: @MadPhysicist Sorry for that, I edit the question I ask.

Comment: Have you considered itertools.product ?

Comment: Thanks for help! @Sci Prog is answer the question what i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to try a simple example before using it on a very big set of numbers,  and with a more complex function.

Here is one program that prints what you want, uses multiprocessing, and should scale for larger lists and more complex functions.

```
import multiprocessing

xlist=[1,2,3]
ylist=[4,5,6]

def enum_tasks():
  for x in xlist:
    for y in ylist:
      yield (x,y)

def product(xy):
  x,y = xy
  return x * y

if __name__ == '__main__':
  CHUNK_SIZE = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
  pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
  for result in pool.imap(product, enum_tasks(), CHUNK_SIZE):
    print result
```

Comment: Thanks for help! That is what I need.